# Redux provider not provides the props to React Component on load

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using Redux for state management. 
I am getting the error that the props are undefined.
Below blocks shows my code,

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={configureStore()}>
        <App />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

store.js

```
function configureStore(state = { rotating: true }) {
  return createStore(rotateReducer,state);
}
```

Browser console:

```
App {props: undefined, context: undefined, refs: {…}, updater: {…}}
on expand this App object in console, 
props: {rotating: true, startAction: ƒ, stopAction: ƒ} (now props are defined).
```

App.js

```
function App() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
        <img 
            src={logo} 
            className={
              "App-logo" + 
              (this.props.rotating ? "":" App-logo-paused")
            } 
            alt="logo" 
            onClick={
              this.props.rotating ? 
                this.props.stopAction : this.props.startAction
            }
          />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

what is the issue on props to App component load?

Comment: Could you provide the `App ` component code as well .

Comment: Where you defined `mapStateToProps ` in the `App` component?

Comment: above the App function...

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  startAction: () => dispatch(startAction),
  stopAction: () => dispatch(stopAction)
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `this` keyword before the props, it's a functional component and `this` is used in `class` components only.

And add props parameter in the function signature.

**Try this**

**Example:**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img
          src={logo}
          className={
            "App-logo" + (props.rotating ? "" : " App-logo-paused")
          }
          alt="logo"
          onClick={
            this.props.rotating ? props.stopAction : props.startAction
          }
        />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ ...state });
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  startAction: () => dispatch(startAction),
  stopAction: () => dispatch(stopAction)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Yes the same way, I did in my code. The browser throws the props are undefined. Seems the provider not passing the props to the App function/Component correctly.

Comment: You have to pass the `props` as the function parameter

Comment: Got It. Since the component defined as function we need to pass the props to function parameter. Else we have to change to Class. Thanks.